# ¿Cómo asignar a una columna el valor de la resta de dos otras columnas?

Tags: mysql

Necesito hacer un cambio en una tabla de una base de datos `MySQL`.

Tengo una tabla con 3 columnas: columna1, columna2 y columna3.

- la columna3 está vacía.
- las otras dos tienen distintos valores numéricos.

Necesito que para cada registro se le asigne a la columna3 el valor de la columna1 - el valor de la columna2.

Tengo una idea de cómo hacerlo con php, pero supongo que habrá alguna forma de hacerlo directamente con una sentencia Mysql.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo harías con PHP? Muestra parte de tu esfuezo

Comment: No acabo de entender el voto positivo ni la tan pronta respuesta: ¿no es mejor esperar a ver si el OP aporta parte de investigación?

Comment: Si no pongo como lo haría por php es porque, como he dicho, tenía una idea de como hacerlo, no que supiera exactamente como hacerlo,pero suponía que sería mucho más sencillo (y no me equivocaba) de la otra forma, y quería ahorrarme el quebradero de cabeza... Lo del voto positivo es porque suponía que sería algo así pero no estaba seguro y antes de estropear nada quería preguntar a algún experto para asegurarme.

Comment: Entiendo. Mi punto es que en este sitio defendemos que quien pregunta aporte una explicación de qué ha intentado, qué falló, etc. Es decir: la finalidad es ayudar, no hacerlo todo desde cero :) Por ello en [ask] recominendan buscar primero, etc. Dicho lo cual, bienvenido al sitio y esperamos verte de nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de hacer una prueba y creo que te bastaría con hacer una sentencia SQL UPDATE de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE tabla SET  colum3 = (colum1 - colum2);
```

De esta forma se actualizarían todos los registros de la columna 3 con la diferencia entre la columna 1 y la 2.

Si quieres solo actualizar ciertos registros deberías utilizar la clausula WHERE, indicando la condición que deben cumplir para actualizarse, por ejemplo que el número de la columna 1 sea mayor a 5, la consulta te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE tabla SET  colum3 = (colum1 - colum2) where colum1 > 5 ;
```

Comment: Esta noche lo pruebo, imaginaba que sería algo sencillo, pero no estaba seguro. GRACIAS

Comment: Comprobado y ha funcionado correctamente, gracias de nuevo...

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido, si ha servido para solucionar tu problema marcala como correcta para que pueda ayudar a otros usuarios @user3219178